# Determining the absence of Truth value of an inequality given assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I have a set of assumptions, say, $x > 0$ and $y > 0$.
So I specified the 
`$Assumptions = x > 0 && y > 0`
Now the inequality $x - y/2 > 0$ does not provide a truth value.

The function `Simplify[x-y/2>0]` produces output `2x>y`, while the function `Simplify[x+y/2>0]` produces output `True`.

I actually want a truth value for expressions. But when a truth value doesn't exist, i.e., it may be either true or false, I want to know that the said inequality can take either.

Then I can just proceed with assuming $x-y/2>0$ and $x-y/2\leq 0$ as two cases.

**Is there a way to figure out that the inequality is undetermined in Mathematica?**

Comment: Think of the FindInstance command.

Comment: It's just telling you in the first instance that `x-y/2` is true when `2x>y`.  It will be False otherwise.  Since MMA doesn't know whether `2x>y`, it can't give you a straight True or False answer.  The second case is obviously True and MMA tells you that.

Comment: Do you mean to ask if such values for `x` and `y` exist that make `x - y/2 > 0` when `x > 0` and `y > 0`? `Simplify` is not the way to go here, but using `Exists` and `Reduce` is a very obvious solution when you actually get to know its existence. `Reduce[Exists[{x, y}, x > 0 && y > 0, x + y/2 > 0], Reals]` returns `True`, which indicates that such values of `x` and `y` exist. What your `Simplify` query for `x + y/2 > 0` with these assumptions tells is that *all* values under these conditions fulfil the requirement. (You can also check `ForAll` usage with `Reduce`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I split the result to four alternatives: value is true for all variable values under assumptions, it's false for all such values, it is neither true nor false for all values (`Both`), or it is not a Boolean value (`Unresolved`):

```
ClearAll@eqnTrueFalseBothUnresolved;
eqnTrueFalseBothUnresolved[var_, eqn_, assum_, dom_:Reals] :=
 If[Reduce[ForAll[var, assum, eqn], dom], True,
  If[Reduce[ForAll[var, assum, !eqn], dom], False, Both, Unresolved],
  Unresolved];
```

Both outcomes are possible:

```
eqnTrueFalseBothUnresolved[{x, y}, x - y/2 > 0, x > 0 && y > 0]
```

> Both

Always true:

```
eqnTrueFalseBothUnresolved[{x, y}, x + y/2 > 0, x > 0 && y > 0]
```

> True

When we don't know the value of `a` we can't be certain of the outcome (if `a` is positive, it'd be `Both`, otherwise `True`):

```
eqnTrueFalseBothUnresolved[{x, y}, x + y/2 > a, x > 0 && y > 0]
```

> Unresolved

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think I was missing the command `ForAll`. Since it checks for all instances in the domain, it can indicate whether there exists a solution to the inequality.